# If any of the cells in a column in a table (MS Word) contains a specific text, display a MsgBox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to do an error-checking code that verifies if some specific cells are completed correctly before running a more elaborate code.

So far, I've written the following code:

```
Dim tabel As Range
Set tabel = ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range
tabel.Select
Dim oCel As Cell
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3)
  For Each oCel In .Cells
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Petent"
    If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
    MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Petent"
    End If
   Next
End With
tabel.Select
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3)
  For Each oCel In .Cells
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Creditor"
    If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
    MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Creditor"
    End If
Next
End With
tabel.Select
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3)
  For Each oCel In .Cells
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Debitor"
    If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
    MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Debitor"
    End If
Next
End With
```

Doing step by step debug, I find that when the specific word is not found in a cell, it skips to the next cell, without displaying the message.

What is the issue in this case?

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior. But you don't give specific instructions how to set up a test case so something could be missing. I inserted a four-colum, four-row table and typed each search term in your code into one cell in column 3. I got three messages for each term.

Comment: Actually, instead of getting message right after it goes over the cell that doesn't contain the word to find, the message box pops up after going through the last row.  I was mislead by this aspect, because my table had a large number of rows and I did step by step calculation. I am sorry for putting you up to testing, I should have set up myself a small test table, before posting. However, I will mark dwirony's post as Answer because it's a far simpler code and it pops out the message right after the cell which doesn't contain those words. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @CindyMeister I THINK the problem here is that while they're looping through cells, they're using `Selection` - the loop doesn't matter at all, they're using `Find` on something else entirely... I was able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already looping through the individual cells, why use `.Find` at all? Just check the value of the cell itself:

```
Dim oCel As Cell

With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3)

    For Each oCel In .Cells
        If InStr(oCel.Range.Text, "Petent") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Petent"
        End If
    Next

    For Each oCel In .Cells
        If InStr(oCel.Range.Text, "Creditor") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Creditor"
        End If
    Next

    For Each oCel In .Cells
        If InStr(oCel.Range.Text, "Debitor") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat Debitor"
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using Find:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, ArrFnd()
ArrFnd = Array("Petent", "Creditor", "Debitor")
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  Set Rng = .Range
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<" & ArrFnd(i) & ">"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found
        If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
        If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 3 Then
          MsgBox "Intr-un dosar nu este inregistrat " & ArrFnd(i)
        End If
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```